# How to update the repo version

Tags: git, repo

This below is the message I see, when I try to repo sync.

> info: A new version of repo is available
>
> error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory 
>   error: could not run gpg. 
>   error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.17'
>
> warning: Skipped upgrade to unverified version

How can I update my repo version?

Comment: you need to install gpg (gnu privacy guard)

Comment: Any download link would be helpful.

Comment: are you on linux? which distro?

Answer (score 15):

This can happen on Linux and Mac. I've personally experienced it on Linux (Ubuntu).

Repo is trying to automatically update itself, but it is failing when trying to verify the key because it can't find `gpg`. To fix it, just install Gnu Privacy Guard (gpg) and run `repo` again:

1. Make sure you have gpg installed.

   - **Linux** `sudo apt-get install gpg`
   - **Mac** (easiest using Homebrew) `brew install gpg`
2. Delete ~/.repoconfig so it sets up gpg correctly: `rm -rf ~/.repoconfig`
3. Run `repo sync` again and watch it update itself.
4. Errors are gone.

Comment: Run `sudo port install gnupg2` if you use MacPorts.